# HorizontalScrollView not displaying the contents - this has to be simple. What am I missing?

Tags: android, android-layout

My code contains a simple HorizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout child. I am tyring to add TextViews programmatically to the LinearLayout. The code executes with NO errors, but none of the TextView(s) are getting displayed. Net net - I am getting a blank activity screen on my Samsung s3. What could I be possibly doing wrong? Any and all help is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

HorizontalScrollActivity.java

```
public class HorizontalScrollActivity extends Activity {
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.horizontal_scroll, menu);
    return true;
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scroll);
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scroll, null);
    HorizontalScrollView ribbon=(HorizontalScrollView)v.findViewById(R.id.ribbon);
    LinearLayout ribbonHolder=(LinearLayout)ribbon.findViewById(R.id.ribbon_holder);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        TextView ribbonItem=new TextView(this);
        ribbonItem.setText("text - "+i);
        ribbonItem.setWidth(100);
        ribbonItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ribbonHolder.addView(ribbonItem);
    }
}
```

}

Corresponding layout xml file (activity_horizontal_scroll.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HorizontalScrollActivity" >
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/ribbon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ribbon_holder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you forget to add your `LinearLayout` to `ScrollView` like: `ribbon.addView(ribbonHolder);`

Comment: Thank you Simple Plan - let me try. But ribbonHolder is already a child of ribbon.

Comment: Why you inflated `activity_horizontal_scroll` view again?

Comment: Hi Simple Plan - Nope your suggestion did not yield result. In fact, it gave a run time exception mentioning that the HorizntalScrollView (i.e. ribbon) can have only one child. I rechecked and found that ribbonHolder (i.e. LinearLayout) already exists within the ribbon.

Comment: Awesome. Than you Simple Plan. That was it. I should not have been inflating activity_horizontal_scroll. I have been coding non stop for the past 10 hours, so I was just not thinking right. Thanks again. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why you inflated `activity_horizontal_scroll` view again?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scroll);

HorizontalScrollView ribbon=(HorizontalScrollView).findViewById(R.id.ribbon);
LinearLayout ribbonHolder=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ribbon_holder);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    TextView ribbonItem=new TextView(this);
    ribbonItem.setText("text - "+i);
    ribbonItem.setWidth(100);
    ribbonItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ribbonHolder.addView(ribbonItem);
}
ribbon.addView(ribbonHolder);
}
```

Try this way and give me feedback on this.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Simple Plan. That was it. I should not have been inflating activity_horizontal_scroll. I have been coding non stop for the past 10 hours, so I was just not thinking right. Thanks again. I upvoted your answer. –  Rajeev Nair 1 min ago   edit